# Is it good idea to save password hash in cookie for authorization

Tags: cookies, hash, passwords, authorization, password-hash

Password hash is the same as in DB.

For exampale, password hash is created by `PHP` function `password_hash`

Answer (score 0):

It is bad idea.

If somebody will steal your passwords, it will be easy to set cookie and authorize in your site.

But you can store signed cookie based on password hash.
When user changes password, he will be unauthorized on all devices.